# What is the equivalent of ANOVA for repeated measures/mixed between-within subjects for categorial variables?

Tags: categorical-data

I would like to test the effect of an intervention on physical activity measured by self-report (IPAQ, International Physical Activity Questionnaire) which has categorial scores. So what is the equivalent of ANOVA for repeted measures/mixed plan for categorial variables?

Comment: Do you mean that your response variable is an ordered categorical variable?

Comment: Yes, the scores of the questionnaire are ordered categorial variables (3 categories: low, medium and high physical activity).